# My app not working with the phone emulator but is working with the browser

Tags: flutter, dart

My app work normal when i use the chrome emulator but when i use a real phone or phone emulator not working and i get this error

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction Android resource linking failed**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.birthday">
   <application
        android:label="birthday"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|gender|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Share your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: @SuganPandurengan i did

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say what is the error without XML file, but I had a similar problem where I changed `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` to some other versions and it resolved the problem.
If this doesen't help share your XML file

Comment: i added the xml file you can see

Comment: i try to chang them nothing